# What do I do about not having access to "target" in Stage 3 javascript decorators?

Tags: javascript, decorator

Decorators are now stage 3. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

I use "target" in the legacy implementation to do lots of things. I've spent a lot of the weekend reading about this current proposal, and it seems pretty dead set on not allowing access to anything aside from the thing being decorated. That means "target" (such as the class) isn't available ever to anything other than class decorators. Even functions passed to addInitializer don't receive the class as an argument.

Am I getting this right? For example, there's no way to decorate a field that could log something like "Class Foo has field Bar" at the start of the program.

Comment: You can use a class decorator together with member decorators - the latter for "tagging" everything that should be logged, the former for logging at the start of the program (or whenever the class is initialised).

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. While I haven't followed the proposal, a cursory search found https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/pull/451 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/466 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/issues/465 which all seem related to your issue

Comment: Thank you. I picked through the issues myself, but must not have known what to look for exactly

Comment: And, to be clear, in the currently documented implementation there is no way to do what I’ve been doing. The issues you cited are all people with the same problem as me that has no solution. Right?